# OpenVPN server not starting after generating config file for client

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-18.04, openvpn

I am new to OpenVPN and to set up a server I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Here is what I get on starting OpenVPN

```
omayr@x556uqk:~$ sudo systemctl start openvpn@server
Job for openvpn@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn@server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Status:

```
omayr@x556uqk:~$ sudo systemctl status openvpn@server
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; indirect; vendor preset
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-02-22 23
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 3740 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/o
 Main PID: 3740 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```